# can I set the http_referer on a pageload?

Tags: php, header, set, spoofing, referer

I was wondering if its possible to set the referer header for the page that is loading?

So set the referer than load the page.

I  have this code that I want to execute and works perfectly but I want to append the referer url to this as well.

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://Domain');
$regex = '/<div\b[^>]+?\bid\s*=\s*"MyID"[^>]*>(?:((?:[^<]++|<(?!\/?div\b[^>]*>))+)|(<div\b[^>]*>(?>(?1)|(?2))*<\/div>))?<\/div>/i';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
//var_dump($match);
echo $match[0];
```

I want to load the div from another page and set the referer to "Domain"

Thanks!

Comment: Not with a bare file_get_contents. You'll need to use streams or curl to set HTTP headers.

Comment: can I set the headers with curl and still display the div contents?

Comment: curl is like zombo.com, anythign is possible.

Comment: gaaaah. don't post code in a comment. it's utterly unreadable. you can edit your question and put it into a properly formatted code block.

Comment: anyways I have a script to set the referer in curl but I cant figure out how to apply the referer and display the div at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

You can set the referrer and many other things and still use `file_get_contents()` tho curl is preferred as its faster and more customizable.

```
<?php 
$url = 'example.com';
$referer = 'Domain';


$header[] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/json,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";

$opts = array('http'=>array('method'=>"GET",
                            'header'=>implode('\r\n',$header)."\r\n".
                            "Referer: $referer\r\n",
                            'user_agent'=> "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008092313 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8"));

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
?>
```

Or you can use curl:

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl-PL; rv:1.9.0.2) Gecko/2008092313 Ubuntu/9.25 (jaunty) Firefox/3.8');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$data = curl_exec($curl);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the contents jsut like you would any time you use curl... by setting CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER so you can use the data...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_REFERER => 'your referer value'
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://Domain'
));

$data= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$regex = '/<div\b[^>]+?\bid\s*=\s*"MyID"[^>]*>(?:((?:[^<]++|<(?!\/?div\b[^>]*>))+)|(<div\b[^>]*>(?>(?1)|(?2))*<\/div>))?<\/div>/i';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
//var_dump($match);
echo $match[0];
```

Comment: whats happening is the script is loading a player and that player is checking the referer and the curl script is not setting the referer for the player which is a second check.  Is there a way to set the script to send the referer in ALL instances?